# On a board view with long columns, scroll by column, or whole board?

Tags: scrolling

In a board view such as shown below, what is the best practice regarding vertical scroll?

- By column
- The whole board

And why?

Scroll vertically column by column: Trello, Asana, Airtable works with vertical scroll by column.
[image: Trello board scroll vertically by column]

The whole view (all the columns): Notion, Jira use this scroll
[image: Notion scroll the whole board]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scroll-by-column is a nice pattern for when there are long columns, and the user wants to examine them one-at-a-time. Benefits:

- It's good for when the user is focused on their own to-do list (out of a group), or when a scrummaster calls on one engineer at a time. Animation (such as the small scrolling interaction of a rolling column) helps draw attention. It can be a bit taxing on a user to find "their column" in a sea of items.
- It's a little easier on people who have vestibular disorders - watching someone share their screen while scrolling a whole page up and down can cause seasickness and other disturbances in sensitive individuals.

Using whole-board scroll is beneficial for getting a quick sense on how many items there are on the board, overall, and which columns have more items than others. It would seem that the platforms that provide column-level scrolling would also allow board/page scrolling as well.